# How to create/generate users moderation with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created an app and installed devise. How can I manage a user when they are signing in? How can I have a list of all the registered members for example?
I can imagine that I have to generate a moderator account with devise but I'm not sure how to deal with this?

Can someone tell me a little bit about managing users with devise?

Answer (score 0):

To manage the registered users, you can start with a scaffold controller for model `User`

```
rails g scaffold_controller User
```

To limit access to this controller you have to implement some kind of authorization that can vary from creating a `is_admin` attribute on the `User` model, to something more advanced like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

My advise is to keep it simple if you are just starting

```
rails g migration add_is_admin_to_users is_admin:boolean
```

And then check in the `UserController` if `current_user.is_admin` is true.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create user controller and view under the admin folder than you can access the devise users.

code:

app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @users = User.all
 end
end
```

same as your view part,  `app/views/admin/users/index.html.erb`

```
<%- model_class = User -%>
  <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human.pluralize.titleize %></h1>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th><%=t '.actions', :default => t("helpers.actions") %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to user.id, "#" %></td>
        <td><%= user.name %></td>

        <td>

          <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
                      edit_admin_user_path(user), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
          <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      admin_user_path(user),
                      :method => :delete,
                      :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm", :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
                      :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-danger' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>


<%= link_to t('.new', :default => t("helpers.links.new")),
            new_admin_user_path,
            :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Now can use normal users/index action to display the devise users list.

Comment: Hey @thiyaram, thanks for your answer, i created both files with the right code in it: index.html.erb and users_controller.rb. I am not sure what to do after ? what are the normal users/index action to display the devise users list? thanks again